# How to let the content of $$..$$ align at left

Tags: amsmath, alignment, alignat

I have the document:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Exercise 7.3\\
A(2)\\
$xy''=y'\ln{(y')}$\\
Let $k=y'$, then $xk'=k\ln{(k)}$\\
$$x\frac{dk}{dx}=k\ln{(k)}$$\\             THIS LINE I WANT IT TO LEFT ALIGN

\end{document}
```

[image: math]

But I want to let the `$$...$$` align at left

have tried `\begin{align}` but then I have to insert `&` to each line to achieve the effect, and when I type 'Let' or 'then', I have to use `\normaltext` to make it not part of italic math equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fleqn` option makes all supported math displays be left aligned, but `$$` is not supported latex syntax and does not work . Use `\[ x\frac{dk}{dx}=k\ln (k) \]`

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\section*{Exercise 7.3}

\subsection*{A(2)}

$xy''=y'\ln (y')$\\
Let $k=y'$, then $xk'=k\ln(k)$
\[x\frac{dk}{dx}=k\ln(k)\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\begin{align}`, and you don't have to use any `&` at any line! Meanwhile, the equations are still aligned left due to your `fleqn` option that you used.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
%
Exercise 7.3\\
A(2)\\
%
\begin{align*}
    xy''=y'\ln{(y')} \\
    \text{Let }  k=y', \text{then }  xk'=k\ln{(k)} \\
    x\frac{dk}{dx}=k\ln{(k)}              %THIS LINE I WANT IT TO LEFT ALIGN
\end{align*}
%
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I would also recommend to never end a line by breaking command `//`. Use new paragraph instead (just leaving a blank line below before starting a new paragraph).